# Selenium firefox webdriver with virtualenv: Exec format error

Tags: selenium, subprocess, virtualenv, geckodriver

I am using Selenium and Virtualenv in Ubuntu14.04 to scrape some code on webpage. After making a virtualenv directory, while activating virtualenv using 
source bin/activate, 
I installed selenium, headless firefox, pyvirtualdisplay and firefox geckodriver.

I installed headless firefox according to [here](http://scraping.pro/use-headless-firefox-scraping-linux/).

And I also Found out that there are different python2.7 folders at
"/usr/lib/python2.7/" and "~/ladder_selenium/lib/python2.7" (ladder_selenium is the Virtualenv directory)

and after I ran a python code which contains

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

, the error below happens.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "predict.py", line 12, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/heyjude/ladder_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/f
self.service.start()
  File "/home/heyjude/ladder_selenium/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/c
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Could you tell me what to fix?

EDIT for the COMMENT BELOW:

```
(ladder_selenium) heyjude@ladder-selenium:~$ export DISPLAY=:99
(ladder_selenium) heyjude@ladder-selenium:~$ firefox
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Comment: Definitely has something to do with the firefox executable. Can you execute it from the command-line manually?

Comment: do you mean by this?

Comment: (ladder_selenium) heyjude@ladder-selenium:~$ export DISPLAY=:99
(ladder_selenium) heyjude@ladder-selenium:~$ firefox
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

Comment: what firefox version is installed? you can also manually download firefox, unpack and than try to start it using /path/to/yourfirefox/firefox-bin

Comment: I used apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build. It's firefox-mozilla-build_50.1.0. Btw, what is difference between apt-get install firefox and apt-get install firefox-mozilla-build?

Comment: I just switched to Chrome Driver, got help from https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/